# Is it possible to integrate tuppers self referential formula?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

(Tuppers self referential formula is described [here](http://tuppers%20self%20referential%20formula) ).

Is it possible to integrate the following function:-

floor(mod(floor(y/17)*2^(-17*floor(x)-mod(floor(y), 17)),2))=1/2

with limits 0 to 17

Comment: In the first place this is not a function, but an inequality defining a set in the plane. It makes no sense to "integrate this function from $0$ to $17$".

Answer (score 0):

The Tupper "self-referential" formula is the inequality

$\left\lfloor \mathrm{mod}\left(\left\lfloor {y \over 17} \right\rfloor 2^{-17 \lfloor x \rfloor - \mathrm{mod}(\lfloor y\rfloor, 17)},2\right)\right\rfloor > {1\over 2}$

You can certainly integrate the expression on the left hand side of the inequality

$T(x,y) = \left\lfloor \mathrm{mod}\left(\left\lfloor {y \over 17} \right\rfloor 2^{-17 \lfloor x \rfloor - \mathrm{mod}(\lfloor y\rfloor, 17)},2\right)\right\rfloor$

between given bounds for $x$ and $y$, but note that for *any* function $f(x,y)$

$\left\lfloor \mathrm{mod}\left(f(x,y),2\right)\right\rfloor \in \{0,1\}$

and by integrating this over a given domain you are simply calculating the area in that domain in which

$\left\lfloor \mathrm{mod}\left(f(x,y),2\right)\right\rfloor  =1$

For example, if you take the domain $0 \le x \lt \infty$ and $0 \le y \lt 17$ then  $\left\lfloor {y \over 17} \right\rfloor =0$ throughout this domain so $T(x,y)=0$ throughout this domain too, and the integral of $T(x,y)$ will be $0$.